# overwriting array list's items after calling notifyDataSetChanged() [java] [android]

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

I have a class like this:

```
public class ComponentMain implements Serializable {

private ArrayList<Integer> componentsIDs;
private int availableCount;

private String component_name;
private String component_desc;
```

and I'm using RecycleView.

In the activity the code looks like this

```
private List<ComponentMain> componentMains = new ArrayList<>();

recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
mAdapter = new ComponentAdapter(getActivity(),componentMains);
recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

And I'm adding element to componentMains.

```
        private List<Component> componentList = new ArrayList<>();        
    //adding data to componentList here.

    String tmp = componentList.get(0).getComponent_name() ;
    ArrayList<Integer> oneComponent = new ArrayList<>();
    oneComponent.add(componentList.get(0).getComponent_id_Integer());

    int i;
    for (i = 1; i< componentList.size(); ++i) {
        if(componentList.get(i).getComponent_name().equals(tmp)) {
            oneComponent.add(componentList.get(i).getComponent_id_Integer());
            tmp = componentList.get(i).getComponent_name();
        } else {

            //ArrayList<Integer> componentsIDs, String component_name, String component_desc
            //
            ComponentMain mainComp = new ComponentMain(oneComponent,componentList.get(i-1).getComponent_name(),componentList.get(i-1).getComponent_desc());
            componentMains.add(mainComp);

            oneComponent.clear();
            oneComponent.add(componentList.get(i).getComponent_id_Integer());
            tmp = componentList.get(i).getComponent_name();
        }
    }

    ComponentMain mainComp = new ComponentMain(oneComponent,componentList.get(i-1).getComponent_name(),componentList.get(i-1).getComponent_desc());
    componentMains.add(mainComp);

    }
```

I'm grouping components by name and storing ArrayList of IDs for each name;
At the end I'm calling

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The problem is after I call **notifyDataSetChanged()** , for every object in **componentMains list**, the value of  **componentsIDs list** is same as the value of the last one in componentsMains list .

**Here's the code od ComponentAdapter class**

```
public class ComponentAdapter extends   RecyclerView.Adapter<ComponentAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

private List<ComponentMain> componentList;
private Context context;

public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    public TextView name,description,availableCount;

    public MyViewHolder(View view) {
        super(view);
        name = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.description);
        available = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.available);

    }
}

public ComponentAdapter(Context context, List<ComponentMain> componentList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.componentList = componentList;
}

@Override
public ComponentAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.component_list_row, parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ComponentAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ComponentMain component = componentList.get(position);

    holder.name.setText(component.getComponent_name());
    holder.description.setText(component.getComponent_desc());
    holder.available.setText(component.getAvailableCount()+"");

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return componentList.size();
}
}
```

Comment: Post your code of  ComponentAdapter class

Comment: Post the code where you set "componentsIDs". Most probably you are setting the same id for every item.

Comment: @sunilsunny No. Because when I list the **componentsIDs** before notifyDataSetChanged() it shows the correct amount.

Comment: Where are you using  componentsIDs, as in your code there is nothing related to  componentsIDs ....

Comment: @Vickyexpert how does it matter. For now I'm just storing that value.

Comment: It's matter, untill you show how you are adding values in that sub list and how you fetch it from sub list how can anyone say what is the issue ?

Comment: @Vickyexpert I updated my question. I hope it matters.

Comment: when you have not added data in componentList, then how can you get it in list ?